# How to get all possible values of a union type to an array (or the other way around)?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
type X = 'a' | 'b';
const xVals = ??? X; // ['a', 'b']
```

Or the other way around (from a list of all possible values get a type which is a union of those all values from an array).

**My goal is to have all possible values listed only once.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternate solution to the `stringTuple` function in @Titian's answer,  as of TypeScript 3.4 you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```js
const xValues = ['a', 'b'] as const; // type: readonly ["a", "b"]
type X = typeof xValues[number]; // type: "a" | "b"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't go from a type to a value. You can go the other way, starting from a value you can get the type. The problem is that the array value `['a', 'b']` would be typed as `string[]` and the union of string literal types would be lost.

The solution to use a function in order to force the compiler to infer a string literal type for the specified values:

```
function stringTuple<T extends [string] | string[]>(...data: T): T {
    return data;
}

let xValues = stringTuple('a', 'b') // typed as ["a", "b"]
type x = typeof xValues[number] // 'a' | 'b'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely (switching to fat-arrow works as well).