# Obtain Type Property value at runtime

Tags: typescript

Consider the following type (generated from a graphql schema):

```js
export type UserPageEntry = {
  readonly __typename?: 'UserPageEntry'
}
```

I'd like to obtain the the type's only property type as a string ('UserPageEntry') at compile type so that I can remove the magic string of 'UserPageEntry' in the code below:

```
   cache.modify({
              optimistic: true,
              id: `UserPageEntry:${userId}`,
```

I was hoping I could use an indexed access type,e.g.

`type x =  UserPageEntry['__typename']`

...
then use it
`${x.toString()}:${userId}`,

Is it possible to get this property's default value or is it erased?

Comment: So you don't have a runtime object to get the property from, I take it.

Comment: unfortunately not part of the mutation result

Comment: I don't think you can. As Titian Cernicova-Dragomir says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53154662/157247), *"You can't go from a type to a value."* Now, that was four years ago, and TypeScript has gotten even more powerful in that time, but I suspect this is a line it still doesn't cross.

Comment: Yup. That is still the case. You can only go from values to types not from types to values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as Titian Cernicova-Dragomir says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53154662/157247):

> You can't go from a type to a value.

But you can have TypeScript check for you that the magic string is in fact correct:

```typescript
const userPageEntryString: UserPageEntry["__typename"] = "UserPageEntry";

const id = `${userPageEntryString}:${userId}`;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAgnlMKCqBnMOABQEMBzMAUQDsE50UBeFAbwCgVOU4wSATGNQA2DAPqiMWaiQC2YAPwAuFAHJ8hUhRp10KtgF82bAMaC8CFAFcCxclVr0AynQCW1MsvW2tD9AG0AInFJMGk5AIBdJhQAr017HQCAbiM+MGMhEh4UU2pzKxsAST5laksZACNCFJMzCxc+aIADABIWaw07bSdXd31FNo64Yv0mpKA)

There are a couple of ways that helps:

- It catches typos
- It catches the magic string if `UserPageEntry["__typename"]` changes later during refactoring

Here's a typo example (but really it illustrates both):

```typescript
const userPageEntryString: UserPageEntry["__typename"] = "UserPaegEntry";
// Error as desired, this is incorrect −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAgnlMKCqBnMOABQEMBzMAUQDsE50UBeFAbwCgVOU4wSATGNQA2DAPqiMWaiQC2YAPwAuFAHJ8hUhRp10KtgF82bAMaC8CFAFcCxclVr0AynQCW1MsvW2tD9AG0AInFJMGk5AIBdJhQAr1IwMm16AIBuNmBUSjg4eBQSPBQ+MDwXHj4AGjQACxcC2pQ3U2ywYwtAJCIOzq7unq6APT6jIuMhEh4UU2pzKxsAST5laksZACNCNJMzCxc+aIADABIWaw07JPRnODcyfUUjk7h5-T2UoA)